# How do you prevent a dpkg installation task to notify a changed state when it runs for the second time?

Tags: deb, dpkg, ansible

There isn't a module for installing .deb packages directly. When you have to run dpkg as a command, it always mark the installation task as one that has changed. I'd some trouble configuring it correctly, so I'm posting here as a public notebook.

Here is the task to install with dpkg:

```
- name: Install old python 
  command: dpkg -i {{ temp_dir }}/{{ item }}
  with_items: 
    - python2.4-minimal_2.4.6-6+precise1_i386.deb
    - python2.4_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
    - libpython2.4_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
    - python2.4-dev_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
```

The files where uploaded to {{temp_dir}} in another task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ansible 1.6 (and newer), the [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html) module has a deb option:

```
- apt: deb=/tmp/mypackage.deb
```

Answer (score 13):

The answer below still works, but newer ansible versions have the [apt module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html). Mariusz Sawicki answer is the preferred one now. I've marked it as the accepted answer.

It'll work just with Ansible version 1.3, when `changed_when` parameter was added. It is a little clumsy, maybe someone can improve the solution. I didn't find the documentation of this "register" object.

```
- name: Install old python 
  command: dpkg --skip-same-version -i {{ temp_dir }}/{{ item }}
  register: dpkg_result
  changed_when: "dpkg_result.stdout.startswith('Selecting')"
  with_items: 
    - python2.4-minimal_2.4.6-6+precise1_i386.deb
    - python2.4_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
    - libpython2.4_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
    - python2.4-dev_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
```

Here you can run the same task and it will just install the first time. After the first time, the packages won't be installed.

There were two modifications. One is the parameter `--skip-same-version` for preventing dpkg to reinstall the software. The other is the register and changed_when attributes. The first time dpkg runs, it prints to stdout a string starting with 'Selecting' and a change is notified. Later it will have a different output. I've tried a more readable condition, but couldn't make it work with a more sofisticated condition that uses  "not" or searches for a substring.

Comment: Neat trick! I'd prefer to check STDERR though: `changed_when: "'already installed' not in dpkg_result.stderr"`

Comment: From the Ansible docs: [Overriding The Changed Result](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result)

Comment: Since with_items, with_dict etc. don't work when using 1.6+ deb parameter, this is the best way to loop over multiple local .deb files to install.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) module with `dpkg_options` parameter:

```
- name: Install old python 
  apt: deb={{ temp_dir }}/{{ item }} dpkg_options="skip-same-version"
  register: dpkg_result
  changed_when: dpkg_result.stderr.find("already installed") == -1
  with_items: 
    - python2.4-minimal_2.4.6-6+precise1_i386.deb
    - python2.4_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
    - libpython2.4_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
    - python2.4-dev_2.4.6-6+{{ ubuntu_release }}1_i386.deb
```

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one since the new apt module takes care of the problem.